# Drush cannot disable civicrm debug

Tags: drupal, debugging, drush

The drush command `drush civicrm-disable-debug` returns error `The drush command 'civicrm-disable-debug' could not be found.  Run 'drush cache-clear drush' to clear the commandfile cache if you have installed new extensions.`

When entering `drush`to get the list of all commands, the disable command is not displayed, but the enable command is. The enable command works, and both are declared in the same way in ~/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/drush/civicrm.drush.inc:

```
/**
 * Implementation of drush_hook_COMMAND_validate for command 'civicrm-enable-debug'
 */
function drush_civicrm_enable_debug_validate() {
  return _civicrm_init();
}

function drush_civicrm_enable_debug() {
  $settings = array(
    'debug_enabled' => 1,
    'backtrace' => 1,
  );

  foreach ($settings as $key => $val) {
    $result = civicrm_api('Setting', 'create', array('version' => 3, $key => $val));

    if ($result['is_error']) {
      drush_log(dt('An error occurred: !message', array('!message' => $result['error_message'])), 'error');
      return;
    }
  }

  drush_log(dt('CiviCRM debug setting enabled.'), 'ok');
}

/**
 * Implementation of drush_hook_COMMAND_validate for command 'civicrm-disable-debug'
 */
function drush_civicrm_disable_debug_validate() {
  return _civicrm_init();
}

function drush_civicrm_disable_debug() {
  $settings = array(
    'debug_enabled' => 0,
    'backtrace' => 0,
  );

  foreach ($settings as $key => $val) {
    $result = civicrm_api('Setting', 'create', array('version' => 3, $key => $val));

    if ($result['is_error']) {
      drush_log(dt('An error occurred: !message', array('!message' => $result['error_message'])), 'error');
      return;
    }
  }

  drush_log(dt('CiviCRM debug setting disabled.'), 'ok');
}
```

What to do to "enable" the "disable" command? Meanwhile, i use phpmyadmin to change the value of the field "debug_enabled" in the table "civicrm_setting" to "i:0;" (without the ").

Config: Drupal 7.53; CiviCRM 4.7.14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `civicrm-disable-debug` command isn't defined in `civicrm_drush_command()`.  See line 155:

```
$items['civicrm-enable-debug'] = array(
  'description' => "Enable CiviCRM Debugging.",
);
```

To solve this problem, you can add this below that:

```
$items['civicrm-disable-debug'] = array(
  'description' => "Disable CiviCRM Debugging.",
);
```

This would be an easy item to submit as a pull request so everyone could benefit.

Comment: I just created an bugreport https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19976. Interesting is that this bug is a long time around (See https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-12517).

Comment: And a pull request https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal/pull/425

Comment: Jon G and @Kainuk. Great thx for solution and follow up!